# Make Pandas groupby act similarly to itertools groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Suppose I have a Python dict of lists like so:

```
{'Grp': ['2'   , '6'   , '6'   , '5'   , '5'   , '6'   , '6'   , '7'   , '7'   , '6'], 
'Nums': ['6.20', '6.30', '6.80', '6.45', '6.55', '6.35', '6.37', '6.36', '6.78', '6.33']}
```

I can easily group the numbers and group key using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
for k, l in groupby(zip(di['Grp'], di['Nums']), key=lambda t: t[0]):
    print k, [t[1] for t in l]
```

Prints:

```
2 ['6.20']
6 ['6.30', '6.80']      # one field, key=6
5 ['6.45', '6.55']
6 ['6.35', '6.37']      # second
7 ['6.36', '6.78']
6 ['6.33']              # third
```

Note the `6` key is separated into three separate groups or fields .

Now suppose I have the equivalent Pandas DataFrame to my dict (same data, same list order and same keys):

```
  Grp  Nums
0   2  6.20
1   6  6.30
2   6  6.80
3   5  6.45
4   5  6.55
5   6  6.35
6   6  6.37
7   7  6.36
8   7  6.78
9   6  6.33
```

If I use Pandas' [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) I am not seeing how to get group by group iteration. Instead, Pandas groups by key value:

```
for e in df.groupby('Grp'):
    print e
```

Prints:

```
('2',   Grp  Nums
0   2  6.20)
('5',   Grp  Nums
3   5  6.45
4   5  6.55)
('6',   Grp  Nums
1   6  6.30            
2   6  6.80                # df['Grp'][1:2] first field
5   6  6.35                # df['Grp'][5:6] second field
6   6  6.37                 
9   6  6.33)               # df['Grp'][9] third field
('7',   Grp  Nums
7   7  6.36
8   7  6.78)
```

Note are the `6` group keys are bunched together; not separate groups.

My question: Is there an equivalent way to use Pandas' groupby so that `6`, for example, would be in three groups in the same fashion as Python's `groupby`?

I tried this:

```
>>> df.reset_index().groupby('Grp')['index'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))
Grp
2                [0]
5             [3, 4]
6    [1, 2, 5, 6, 9]         # I *could* do a second groupby on this...
7             [7, 8]
Name: index, dtype: object
```

But it is still grouped by overall `Grp` key and I would need to do a second groupby on the `nd.array` to split the sub groups of each key out.

Comment: Interesting question. What object should be returned in this case though? I mean, `groupby` is designed to return an object with unique keys, but that's not possible here. How do you want distinguish between duplicate keys (the different groups of 6s)?

Comment: Sometimes the uninterrupted run of keys is another element of data. The presence of another key indicates something. Such as: time intervals or data readings. Once you have a different interval in the series, that is a different field. I want uniterupted runs of similar keys -- just like itertools does.

Comment: There's a method [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pydata/V3p37GRxgNY/Ca3mmXikYUwJ) that could provide a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, not to be cheeky, but why not just use Python's `groupby` on the DataFrame by using [iterrows](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/basics.html#iterrows)? That is what it is there for:

```
>>> df
  Grp  Nums
0   2  6.20
1   6  6.30
2   6  6.80
3   5  6.45
4   5  6.55
5   6  6.35
6   6  6.37
7   7  6.36
8   7  6.78
9   6  6.33

>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> for k, l in groupby(df.iterrows(), key=lambda row: row[1]['Grp']):
        print k, [t[1]['Nums'] for t in l]
```

Prints:

```
2 ['6.20']
6 ['6.30', '6.80']
5 ['6.45', '6.55']
6 ['6.35', '6.37']
7 ['6.36', '6.78']
6 ['6.33']
```

To try and make Panda's `groupby` act in the way you want is probably asking for so many stacked methods that you won't be able to follow it when you reread in the future.

Comment: To answer your question, it is probably slower.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat: Probably slower to execute on larger data frames true, but the alternatives are probably slower for the programmer to write.

Answer (score 22):

First you can identify which elements in the `Grp` column differ from the previous and get the cumulative sum to form the groups you need:

```
In [9]:
    diff_to_previous = df.Grp != df.Grp.shift(1)
    diff_to_previous.cumsum()
Out[9]:

0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    4
6    4
7    5
8    5
9    6
```

So you can then do

```
df.groupby(diff_to_previous.cumsum())
```

to get the desired groupby object

Answer (score 2):

You basically want to create a new column to index your desired grouping order, and then use that for grouping.  You keep the index number the same until the value in `Grp` changes.

For your data, you would want something like this:

```
   Grp  Nums new_group
0    2  6.20         1
1    6  6.30         2
2    6  6.80         2
3    5  6.45         3
4    5  6.55         3
5    6  6.35         4
6    6  6.37         4
7    7  6.36         5
8    7  6.78         5
9    6  6.33         6
```

Where you can now group on both `new group` and `Grp`:

```
df.groupby(['new_group', 'Grp']).Nums.groups
{(1, 2): [0],
 (2, 6): [1, 2],
 (3, 5): [3, 4],
 (4, 6): [5, 6],
 (5, 7): [7, 8],
 (6, 6): [9]
```

I used this method to create the new column:

```
df['new_group'] = None
for n, grp in enumerate(df.Grp):
if n is 0:
    df.new_group.iat[0] = 1    
elif grp == df.Grp.iat[n - 1]:
    df.new_group.iat[n] = df.new_group.iat[n - 1]
else:
    df.new_group.iat[n] = df.new_group.iat[n - 1] + 1
```

Note that this answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pydata/V3p37GRxgNY/Ca3mmXikYUwJ) has the same idea (thanks @ajcr for the link), but in a much more succinct representation:

```
>>> df.groupby((df.Grp != df.Grp.shift()).cumsum()).Nums.groups
{1: [0], 2: [1, 2], 3: [3, 4], 4: [5, 6], 5: [7, 8], 6: [9]
```

Comment: Damn! I just read this after posting my answer which I was very pleased with... I swear it was my own ; P

Comment: I guess I am just starting in `Pandas` but how would I get the keys and rows from `df` using `{1: [0], 2: [1, 2], 3: [3, 4], 4: [5, 6], 5: [7, 8], 6: [9]`? I see how the pairs match, but I am having trouble translating that into a slice or somthic Pythonic familiar to me... Sorry...

Comment: `df.groupby(['new_group', 'Grp']).Nums.groups.keys()` dict_keys([(1, 2), (2, 6), (4, 6), (6, 6), (5, 7), (3, 5)]

Comment: `[df.loc[(df.new_group == k1) & (df.Grp == k2), :] for k1, k2 in df.groupby(['new_group', 'Grp']).Nums.groups.keys()]`  Note that groups is a dictionary with no consistent order, so you probably want to resort your list.