# Remove consecutive duplicates while keeping the max value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove consecutive duplicates from column X while keeping the entry with the max value based on column Y, unfortunately with no success.
The data frame is as follow:

| idx | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 3 |
| 1 | B | 2 |
| 2 | A | 7 |
| 3 | A | 10 |
| 4 | B | 1 |
| 5 | C | 4 |
| 6 | A | 3 |
| 7 | A | 3 |

What I want to achieve is:

| idx | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 3 |
| 1 | B | 2 |
| 3 | **A** | **10** |
| 4 | B | 1 |
| 5 | C | 4 |
| 7 | **A** | **3** |

Most of the solutions I found just remove the duplicates tout court without accounting for any repeating pattern.

Please note that the duplicates might have the same value.

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply an [itertools-style-groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683492/make-pandas-groupby-act-similarly-to-itertools-groupby) and then [keep the rows where Y is maximal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby).

```
>>> df 
   idx  X   Y
0    0  A   3
1    1  B   2
2    2  A   7
3    3  A  10
4    4  B   1
5    5  C   4
6    6  A   3
7    7  A   5
>>> y_max = df.groupby(df['X'].ne(df['X'].shift()).cumsum())['Y'].transform('max')
>>> df[df['Y'] == y_max] 
   idx  X   Y
0    0  A   3
1    1  B   2
3    3  A  10
4    4  B   1
5    5  C   4
7    7  A   5
```

edit:

Initial solution had a bug and only produced the correct idx column by accident.

edit 2:

If you only want to keep one row per group, you can use

```
>>> y_idxmax = df.groupby(df['X'].ne(df['X'].shift()).cumsum())['Y'].idxmax()
>>> df.loc[y_idxmax] 
   idx  X   Y
0    0  A   3
1    1  B   2
3    3  A  10
4    4  B   1
5    5  C   4
7    7  A   5
```

Credit goes to [Ch3steR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12416453/ch3ster) for this one.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to add that the duplicates might have the same value. Your first solution was producing the right amount of values on my full dataset.

Comment: @massigarg yes, but the first solution can produce a wrong idx column. To clarify, you only want to keep the first row per group where Y is maximal?

Comment: Yes correct., something like max(Yi, Yi+1)

Comment: @timgeb Or you could use [`GroupBy.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) here. Maybe something like this `idx = df.groupby(itertools-style-grouping)['Y'].idxmax(); df.loc[idx, :] # or df.reindex(idx)`

Comment: @massigarg see Ch3steR's comment

Comment: @Ch3steR cool, that will only keep one row per group where Y is maximal.

Answer (score 1):

Or I'd prefer just simply only specify the groups in the `groupby` parameters:

```
df.groupby(df['X'].ne(df['X'].shift()).cumsum(), as_index=False).max()
```

Or:

```
df.groupby(df['X'].ne(df['X'].shift()).cumsum()).max().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Both output:

```
   idx  X   Y
0    0  A   3
1    1  B   2
2    3  A  10
3    4  B   1
4    5  C   4
5    7  A   5
```

Comment: This produces the right idx column "by accident", because coincidentally the maximum Y value is always at the highest idx value (per group). If you switch the 7 and the 10 in the original dataframe the result will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Create a column which heaps consecutives into one group

```
   df['temp']=(~(df['X']==df['X'].shift())|(df['X'].shift(-1)==df['X'])).cumsum()
```

groupby the group of consecutives and filter out wherevalues of Y are equal to maximum in each group. Drop the temp column

```
df[df.groupby('temp')['Y'].transform(lambda x:(x==x.max()))].drop(columns=['temp'])
```

A neater way is not to create column but save the groups of consecutives into a variable and groupby the variable as follows

```
s=(~(df['X']==df['X'].shift())|(df['X'].shift(-1)==df['X'])).cumsum()
print(df[df.groupby(s)['Y'].transform(lambda x:(x==x.max()))])

    idx  X   Y
0    0  A   3
1    1  B   2
3    3  A  10
4    4  B   1
5    5  C   4
7    7  A   5
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out the already given answers right away, so I wrote a simple script to do the same. It takes the indices that have duplicate values and drop them by comparing two at a time.

Check the code below -

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'X':['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A'], 
        'Y': [3, 2, 12, 7, 10, 1, 4, 3, 5]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

mask = data['X'] == data['X'].shift()

to_check = data.loc[mask].index.tolist()

for i, _ in enumerate(to_check):
    index = to_check[i]
    if data.iloc[index]['Y'] > data.iloc[index - 1]['Y']:
        data.drop(index - 1, axis=0, inplace=True)
        data.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    else:
        data.drop(index, axis=0, inplace=True)
        data.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

    to_check = [value - 1 for value in to_check]

print(data)

# OUTPUT

   X   Y
0  A   3
1  B   2
2  A  12
3  B   1
4  C   4
5  A   5
```