# How do I keep the first entry from consecutive entries in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

With the following DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
random.seed(3)
df = pd.DataFrame( 
  data=[random.sample(["A","B"],1) for i in range(6)],
  columns=["category"] )
```

We get:

[image]

**How do I get only the first row for each consecutive category group?**

> Note: the data can contain an arbitrary number of repeats - I only want the first of each consecutive group.

Expected would be:

```
  category
0  A
2  B
4  A
```

I hoped that the `sort` flag from `groupby()` would solve this, but it nevertheless treats all occurences of category as a group - not consecutive ones:

```py
df.groupby("category").head(1)
```

[image]

As I am learning pandas and my `DataFrame` can become very large I'm searching for a pandas native solution and not iterating over the array or `DataFrame`.

While the answers from [Make Pandas groupby act similarly to itertools groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32683492/275195) can be applied here, the posed question is different. As such I would leave this question open so it's easier to find an answer.

Comment: do you always have duplicates in pairs?

Comment: Nope. Can be any amount of consecutive entries. In the real world I try to get state changes events that are thrown from other fields as well.

Comment: this hsould work `df[(df.ne(df.shift())).any(axis=1)]` since the question is closed I cannot post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the best solution:

```py
(df
    .assign(equal_to_previous = lambda x: x['category']==x['category'].shift(1))
    .loc[lambda x: ~x['equal_to_previous']]
    .drop(columns=['equal_to_previous'])
)
```

Or just

```
df.loc[lambda x: x['category']!=x['category'].shift(1)]
```

The trick is to filter on the category not being the same as the previous row's.